# What type of biome is this?

Tags: ecology

There is a region that gets about 812mm of precipitation and is mildly hot all year long.

I believe this region is a tropical savanna, but I'm not 100% sure.  Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the definitions of a tropical savanna I'm afraid. Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 5):

Well, first of all 812mm is a pretty precise value to be preceded by the word "about". "Mildly hot", on the other hand, is too vague a term for your question to be answerable. If you update your question with better parameters, you may get more helpful answers.

In any case, according to [this page](https://php.radford.edu/~swoodwar/biomes/?page_id=105), a tropical savanna has mean monthly temperatures at or above 64°F (~18°C), which may or may not qualify as "mildly hot" by your standards, and annual precipitation averages between 30 and 50 inches which means between 762mm and 1270mm.

So, I what you are describing *could be* a tropical savanna, but as I said before, I can't tell unless you update your question with more information. Have a look at [this site](http://www.climate-charts.com/World-Climate-Maps.html#rain), it may be of help.

Comment: i made a typo.  i updated my question

Comment: Well, in that case @user832680, it may well be a tropical savanna :).